# Yeoman Office Add-in : Change the logo

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I created a Outlook add-in that does what I want, but I can't seem to change the image on the logo. I replaced all of the default icon-xx.png files in /assets with my own .png file (and kept the same names), but it won't pick up even after running *npm run build* etc.

Can someone tell me what the rules around these files are? Do they need to be a certain size or something?

Answer (score 0):

The web browser and Office applications may cache files. You can clear the browser and Office cache. You can delete the content of the following folders:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\
```

If the following folder exists, delete its contents too:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\#!123\INetCache\
```

Read more about that in the [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) article.